# use "rewrite" and "try_files" together [Nginx]

Tags: linux, nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I removed the ".php" suffix at the end of the PHP files on the Nginx server with the following code, but this time I cannot send some data to the server.

```
try_files $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
```

Some links on the site are sent with Ajax, and the ".php" extension is not available at the end of these links. E.g; https://panel.example.com/app/controller/ajax/collect

For example, when I want to access the "/collect" file that I want to access via Ajax or directly, I get the error "File not found". Because I do "rewrite" with the code below and provide a clean URL.

```
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /index.php?cmd=$1&scd=$2 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?cmd=$1 last;
```

Sample link: https://panel.example.com/[details|cat|profile]/[subPages(productID, username..)]

As a result, the above codes are correct and working, but not working at the same time together. How can I run these two codes at the same time?

[Full Nginx vHost File](https://pastebin.com/Uk4X8dqt)

Answer (score 4):

You could try following approach:

```
location ~ ^/(?<cmd>[^/]+)/(?<scd>[^/]+) {
    try_files /index.php?cmd=$cmd&scd=$scd =404;
}

location ~ ^/(?<cmd>[^/]+)/ {
    try_files /index.php?cmd=$cmd =404;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$args;
}
```

We use nginx location matching algorithm here to first check matching of URL to regular expressions and then taking appropriate action for that URL.

I am using named captures here `?<cmd>` to make variable names more clear.

Also, the `?$` part at end of regular expression is removed, since it makes no difference. Both `?$` and empty match any string.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I got a 404 Error but if I go to this address, I don't get any error;
`https://panel.example.com/index?cmd=login` - [In order not to mislead you, full conf. I am sharing the content](https://pastebin.com/Uk4X8dqt)

Comment: no paste the config dont use a nopaste service